# Xamarin - Set up cross platform Hello World App

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am new to xamarin and I want to make a cross platform iOS and Android Hello World app. I am mostly an objective-c programmer and I am having trouble setting this up. I am trying to follow this 
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/visual_studio_with_xamarin/cross_platform_visual_studio_project_setup_walkthrough/

on the xamarin docs, but it seems some of the instructions are a bit out of date, as I can't see under number 2. this anywhere on my xamarin.

[image]

I have also looked at their iOS and Android iOS hello World app found here.

http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/HelloWorld_iPhone/

and here,

http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/HelloWorld/

But theses aren't cross platform.

So what I am looking is for how to set up xamarin for a basic hello world app.

I have looked all over their docs and stackover flow for a basic walkthrough of this and can't find it, and think the community would benefit from a simple way to set up a simple cross platform app.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you would put shared code in Portable Class Library (just below your selection) and reference this project from native projects (iOS, Android, whatever). That's one option.
Second option is to put shared code in a project and link the source files to native projects so they are part of native applications. This approach is more messy and requires #if conditional statements.
The third approach is to go with Xamarin Forms which makes code reusable as much as possible.